# Implementar filas para WebSocket

Tags: javascript, c#, html5, socket, websocket

Estou desenvolvendo um servidor de `WebSocket` que irá controlar multi conexões de clientes, funcionará basicamente como um chat, será uma especie de jogo **multiplayer**, depois de muitas pesquisas e alguns testes percebi que ao utilizar `Socket` para mensagens em **assíncrono** não é possível saber se a mensagem realmente chegou ao client\servidor e ainda existe o risco das mensagens chegarem na **ordem errada** e isso serial crucial em um jogo multiplayer, depois de algumas pesquisas vi que a solução para isso erá implementar uma **fila de mensagens** para o socket, implementar a fila aparentemente é tranquilo teoricamente seria adicionar todas as mensagens ao fim da fila e enviar as mensagem da primeira posição e assim respectivamente, mas a minha duvida é como terei a certeza que a primeira mensagem foi enviada para enviar a segunda da fila e assim por diante, se eu ter que implementar um **ouvinte** para isso ou seja uma resposta do servidor alem de eu ter que informar de qual mensagem é a resposta isso influenciaria na **latência** da minha conexão que por sinal precisa ser baixa, estou com dificuldade de como resolver isso.

A aplicação de servidor é feita em `C#`  estou utilizando o framework `Alchemy`
As aplicações clientes são javascript utilizando `WebSockets`(`HTML5`)

Comment: A fila de mensagens é persistida?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez não é persistida

Answer (score 4):

Você pode estudar a funcionalidade básica do TCP, que prevê a correta ordenação dos pacotes.

como sua conexão não é persistente você precisará basicamente de um controle dentro do pacote, um ID iniciando em 0 que é incrementado a cada transporte, assim no servidor é possível recriar a ordem das mensagens partindo dos ID's.

Answer (score 3):

referente a "duvida é como terei a certeza que a primeira mensagem foi enviada para enviar a segunda da fila e assim por diante..."

É o seguinte, em socket, o lado do server consegue "ouvir" uma cliente, quando o cliente enviar uma mensagem para o server ele irá fazer a rotina programada para aquela mensagem e poderá fazer um retorno para o cliente(ou todos que estiverem ouvindo tipo multiplayer), caso queira uma confirmação de quem recebeu recebeu a mensagem do servidor, poderá programar no cliente outro envio de mensagem para o servidor dizendo que foi tal mensagem foi recebida por tal cliente.

Answer (score 0):

Para criar um servidor socket multi client, é necessário guardar os IDs das conexões clientes em uma fila, pode ser um simples `array` onde em cada conexão recebida é armazenado o array da conexão que será usado para enviar as mensagens específicas.

Ao montar essa lista é importante pensar em como vai poder recuperar o ID da conexão do cliente, por exemplo usar o nome de usuário como chave do array e o valor o ID da conexão.

Quando for necessário enviar uma mensagem específica para este cliente, poderá recuperar a conexão, escrever no buffer dele e continuar o processamento. Caso ocorra algum erro ao tentar escrever no buffer do cliente, saberá que a mensagem não foi entregue.

Sobre a fila de mensagens que o servidor recebe, nada mais é do que uma nova linha que foi escrita no buffer do servidor que é recuperada. Se for necessário criar uma fila de comandos recebidos pelo servidor, terá que definir um padrão de mensagens para que possa interpretar e separar quando o server receber os novos comandos.

Aqui está um exemplo de implementação: http://ashishware.com/websocksample.shtml

Fiz uma explicação sobre o funcionamento porem com implementação em PHP em [Enviar mensagem para usuário específico em Websocket PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/61002/enviar-mensagem-para-usu%C3%A1rio-espec%C3%ADfico-em-websocket-php/98407#98407)