# Enviar mensagem para usuário específico em Websocket PHP

Tags: php, javascript, websocket

Tenho uma aplicação de chat em tempo real com Websocket. Mas, no momento ela envia mensagens para o todos os usuários, gostaria de saber como faço para enviar para um usuário específico. No caso, quando eu clicar no usuário (de uma lista que aparece ao lado), ele começar uma conversa com esse devido usuário.

Tenho os seguintes dados sendo retornados via JSON:

```
//ENVIA COM O ENTER
    $('#message').on('keydown', function(e) {
        var mymessage = $('#message').text(); //get message text
        var msg = $.trim(mymessage);
        var myname = $('.myname').text(); //get user name
        var mensagem = 'mensagem='+mymessage;
        var from = $('.myname').attr('id');
        var to = $('p.nome-informacoes').attr('id');
        var code = e.which || e.keyCode;

        if (e.which == 13 && e.shiftKey == false) {
            if(code == 13){
                if(mensagem != ''){

                    if(mymessage == "" || mymessage.length === 0 || !mymessage.trim()){return false;}
                    else{
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url : 'sys/chat.php',
                            data: 'acao='+'inserir'+'&para='+to+'&mensagem='+mymessage,
                            success: function(html){}
                        });

//AQUI ELE PEGA OS DADOS VIA JSON QUE VÃO SER ENVIADOS PARA O USUÁRIO ESPECÍFICO                        
                            var msg = {
                            message: mymessage,
                            name: myname,
                            from: from,
                            to: to,
                            color : '<?php echo $colours[$user_colour]; ?>'
                            };
                            //convert and send data to server
                            websocket.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
                        }

                    }
                }

                return false;
            }
        })


websocket.onmessage = function(ev) {
        var msg = JSON.parse(ev.data); //PHP sends Json data
        //console.log(msg);
        var type = msg.type; //message type
        var mensagem = msg.message; //message text
        var umsg = $.trim(mensagem);
        var uname = msg.name; //user name
        var ucolor = msg.color; //color
        var status = msg.status;
        var myname = $('.myname').text();
        var nome_user = $('.comecar').attr('title');
        var id = $('p.nome-informacoes').attr('id');
        var id_de = $('.myname').attr('id');
        var from = msg.from;
        var to = msg.to;
        var data = [];

        //AQUI ELE VAI ADICIONANDO ALGUMAS INFORMAÇÕES DE CADA USUÁRIO PARA PODER DIRECIONAR A MENSAGEM PARA USUÁRIO CORRETO
        data.push({'user': uname, 'message': umsg, 'from': from, 'to': to });
        var dados_user = JSON.stringify(data)
        var parser     = JSON.parse(dados_user);

        for(i in dados_user){
            console.log(parser[i]);
        }



        //console.log(localStorage.length);
        if(type == 'usermsg' && umsg.length > 0)
        {
            $("#message_box").animate({"scrollTop": $('#message_box')[0].scrollHeight}, 1);
            $(teste2).append("<div class='mensagem'><span class=\"user_name outro\" nome=\""+uname+"\" style=\"color:#"+ucolor+"\">"+uname+"</span> : <pre><span class=\"user_message\">"+umsg+"</span></pre></div>");

        }

        if(type == 'system' )
        {
            $('#jan_'+id+'').append("<div class=\"system_msg\">"+umsg+"</div>");

        }

        $('#message').text(''); //reset text
        $('.input').val('');
    };
```

Comment: Nesse caso, toda a lógica deverá ficar no backend. Pode identificar pelo id da conexão do usuário (eu faço isso pelo Ratchet PHP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abaixo vamos entender como o funcionamento de um servidor de Socket.

**server.php**

```
$host = '192.168.0.28'; // Host do servidor para conexão
$port = '9000'; // Porta do servidor para conexão
$null = NULL; // Variável nula auxilar

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING);

// Permite o script rodar infinitamente para esperar por conexões
set_time_limit(0);

// Ativa a saída implicita do buffer, isto é, assim que houver alguma
// tiver uma modificação no buffer, é enviado para a tela e o buffer esvaziado.
ob_implicit_flush();

// Cria o servidor socket
$socketServer = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
// Seta a porta como reutilizável
socket_set_option($socketServer, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);

// Amarra socket com o host especificado
socket_bind($socketServer, 0, $port);

// Escuta a porta
socket_listen($socketServer);

// Cria uma lista de sockets que serão escutados
$clients = array($socketServer);

// Armazena o nome dos usuários.
$usersList = array();

// Inicia um loop infinito para que o servidor estaj sempre apto a receber as
// mensagens e receber novas conexões.
while (true) {
    // Controla multiplas conexões copiando a lista para verificar quais as
    // conexões possui alterações.
    $changed = $clients;
    // Verifica se existe sockets com alterações
    socket_select($changed, $null, $null, 0, 10);

    // Testa por novas conexões
    if (in_array($socketServer, $changed)) {
        // Aceita nova conexão
        $socket_new = socket_accept($socketServer);

        // Adiciona o scket client na lista
        $clients[] = $socket_new;

        // Lê os dados enviados pelo novo socket
        $header = socket_read($socket_new, 1024);

        // Envia a resposta do servidor com informações sobre a conexão aceita
        perform_handshaking($header, $socket_new, $host, $port);

        // Obtem o endereço IP do socket conectado.
        socket_getpeername($socket_new, $ip);

        // Prepara a mensagem de boas vindas
        $response = mask(json_encode(array(
            'type'=>'system',
            'message'=> $ip. ' connected'
        )));

        // Envia a mensagem para todos indicando que uma nova pessoa entrou.
        send_message($response);

        // Remove a nova conexão da lista de sockets modificados.
        $found_socket = array_search($socket_new, $changed);
        unset($changed[$found_socket]);
    }

    // Verifica todos os outros sockets modificados que foram alterados
    foreach ($changed as $changed_socket) {

        // Verifica por dados recebidos inciando um loop de leitura do buffer
        // recebido inteiro.
        while (socket_recv($changed_socket, $buf, 1024, 0) >= 1) {
            // Desmascara os dados
            $received_text = unmask($buf);

            // Interpreta os dados
            $tst_msg = json_decode($received_text);

            $user_name = $tst_msg->name;
            $user_toname = $tst_msg->toname;
            $user_message = $tst_msg->message;
            $user_color = $tst_msg->color;

            // Registra o nome do usuário
            $found_socket = array_search($changed_socket, $clients);
            $usersList[$found_socket] = $user_name;

            // Prepara os dados para resposta
            $response_text = mask(json_encode(array(
                'type'=>'usermsg',
                'name'=>$user_name,
                'toname'=>$user_toname,
                'message'=>$user_message,
                'color'=>$user_color
            )));

            // Envia mensagem para um usuário específico ou para todo mundo
            if ($user_toname) {
                $key = array_search($user_toname, $usersList);
                send_message($response_text, $key);
            } else {
                send_message($response_text);
            }
            break 2; // Finaliza este loop
        }

        $buf = socket_read($changed_socket, 1024, PHP_NORMAL_READ);

        // Verifica por clientes desconectados
        if ($buf === false) {
            // Remove o cliente da lista
            $found_socket = array_search($changed_socket, $clients);
            socket_getpeername($changed_socket, $ip);
            unset($clients[$found_socket]);
            unset($usersList[$found_socket]);

            // Notifica a todos que o usuário desconectou
            $response = mask(json_encode(array('type'=>'system', 'message'=>$ip.' disconnected')));
            send_message($response);
        }
    }
}
// Finaliza o socket do servidor
socket_close($socketServer);

function send_message($msg, $key = false) {
    global $clients;
    if($key !== false) {
        if (isset($clients[$key])) {
            socket_write($clients[$key],$msg,strlen($msg));
        }
    } else {
        foreach($clients as $changed_socket) {
            socket_write($changed_socket,$msg,strlen($msg));
        }
    }
    return true;
}


// Desmascara os dados recebidos
function unmask($text) {
    $length = ord($text[1]) & 127;
    if($length == 126) {
        $masks = substr($text, 4, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 8);
    }
    elseif($length == 127) {
        $masks = substr($text, 10, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 14);
    }
    else {
        $masks = substr($text, 2, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 6);
    }
    $text = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); ++$i) {
        $text .= $data[$i] ^ $masks[$i%4];
    }
    return $text;
}

// Codifica as mensagens para transferir para o cliente
function mask($text) {
    $b1 = 0x80 | (0x1 & 0x0f);
    $length = strlen($text);

    if($length <= 125) {
        $header = pack('CC', $b1, $length);
    } elseif ($length > 125 && $length < 65536) {
        $header = pack('CCn', $b1, 126, $length);
    } elseif ($length >= 65536) {
        $header = pack('CCNN', $b1, 127, $length);
    }
    return $header.$text;
}

// Realiza handshake com o novo cliente
function perform_handshaking ($receved_header,$client_conn, $host, $port) {
    $headers = array();
    $lines = preg_split("/\r\n/", $receved_header);
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        $line = chop($line);
        $matches = array();
        if (preg_match('/\A(\S+): (.*)\z/', $line, $matches)) {
            $headers[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
        }
    }

    $secKey = $headers['Sec-WebSocket-Key'];
    $secAccept = base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($secKey . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11')));
    //hand shaking header
    $upgrade  = "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\n" .
    "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" .
    "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
    "WebSocket-Origin: $host\r\n" .
    "WebSocket-Location: ws://$host:$port/demo/shout.php\r\n".
    "Sec-WebSocket-Accept:$secAccept\r\n\r\n";
    socket_write($client_conn,$upgrade,strlen($upgrade));
}
```

Para executar o servidor entre no terminal e execute

```
php -q server.php
```

Arquivo de exemplo cliente

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='UTF-8' />
        <style type="text/css">
            <!--
            .chat_wrapper {
                width: 500px;
                margin-right: auto;
                margin-left: auto;
                background: #CCCCCC;
                border: 1px solid #999999;
                padding: 10px;
                font: 12px 'lucida grande',tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
            }
            .chat_wrapper .message_box {
                background: #FFFFFF;
                height: 150px;
                overflow: auto;
                padding: 10px;
                border: 1px solid #999999;
            }
            .chat_wrapper .panel input{
                padding: 2px 2px 2px 5px;
            }
            .system_msg{color: #BDBDBD;font-style: italic;}
            .user_name{font-weight:bold;}
            .user_message{color: #88B6E0;}
            -->
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $colours = array('007AFF', 'FF7000', 'FF7000', '15E25F', 'CFC700', 'CFC700', 'CF1100', 'CF00BE', 'F00');
        $user_colour = array_rand($colours);

        ?>

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var wsUri = "ws://192.168.0.28:9000/demo/server.php";
                websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);

                websocket.onopen = function (ev) {
                    $('#message_box').append("<div class=\"system_msg\">Conectado!</div>");
                };

                $('#send-btn').click(function () {
                    var mymessage = $('#message').val();
                    var myname = $('#name').val();
                    var toname = $('#toname').val();

                    if (myname === "") {
                        alert("Entre com algum nomde");
                        return;
                    }
                    if (mymessage === "") {
                        alert("Entre com aguma mensagem");
                        return;
                    }


                    var msg = {
                        message: mymessage,
                        name: myname,
                        toname: toname,
                        color: '<?php echo $colours[$user_colour]; ?>'
                    };

                    websocket.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
                });


                websocket.onmessage = function (ev) {
                    var msg = JSON.parse(ev.data);
                    var type = msg.type;
                    var umsg = msg.message;
                    var uname = msg.name;
                    var ucolor = msg.color;

                    console.log(type);
                    if (type === 'usermsg') {
                        $('#message_box').append("<div><span class=\"user_name\" style=\"color:#" + ucolor + "\">" + uname + "</span> : <span class=\"user_message\">" + umsg + "</span></div>");
                    } else if (type === 'system') {
                        $('#message_box').append("<div class=\"system_msg\">" + umsg + "</div>");
                    }

                    $('#message').val('');
                };

                websocket.onerror = function (ev) {
                    $('#message_box').append("<div class=\"system_error\">Um erro ocorreu - " + ev.data + "</div>");
                };
                websocket.onclose = function (ev) {
                    $('#message_box').append("<div class=\"system_msg\">Conexão finalizada</div>");
                };
            });
        </script>
        <div class="chat_wrapper">
            <div class="message_box" id="message_box"></div>
            <div class="panel">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" maxlength="10" style="width:20%"  />
                <input type="text" name="toname" id="toname" placeholder="To Name" maxlength="10" style="width:20%"  />
                <input type="text" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message" maxlength="80" style="width:40%" />
                <button id="send-btn">Send</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Este exemplo não considera um limite de conexão de clientes, o que é necessário ter um controle, pois para cada cliente maior é o processamento exigido pelo servidor.

Para exibir a lista de usuário online, basta criar um comando que será enviado de tempos em tempos para o servidor, que irá retornar a variável `$usersList`.

Comment: Cara muito obrigado pela resposta, e desculpe pela demora pra marcar como resposta correta, pois quando vi pela primeira vez, eu não havia prestado atenção.

Comment: Opa sem problemas, espero ter ajudado ;)

Comment: Tens algum contato? Gostaria de tirar algumas dúvidas sobre websocket se possível.

Comment: Talk marcusagmaia@gmail.com ou e-mail contato@marcusmaia.com.br por esses meios te passo outros

Comment: Valeu cara, enviei um convite no hangout pra vc.